# css, jquery adjust curved lines between draggable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bezier

I have drawn a boxes and curved lines. The boxes are draggable. I am trying to fit the lines with boxes such that the lines keep resizing where ever the boxes are dragged to any area which i am failed to achieve. My objective is to connect A with B and C.

```js
const coordinates = function() {

  $(".line").each(function() {
    const [box1, box2] = $(this).data("connect").split(',');
    const $b1 = $(box1);
    const $b2 = $(box2);
    
    const x1 = $b1.offset().left + $b1.width()/2;
    const y1 = $b1.offset().top + $b1.height()/2;
  
    const x2 = $b2.offset().left + $b2.width()/2;
    const y2 = $b2.offset().top + $b2.height()/2;

    moveLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, $(this)); 
  });

   
}

coordinates();

function moveLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, $line) {
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    var offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    var offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;
    
    $line.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });
}

$('.box').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#line1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  /*transform: rotate(222deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(222deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(222deg);*/
}
/* curved line*/
.line {
  height:150px;
  margin:10px 200px;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  --l:3px;  /* Thickness of the curve */
  --r:90px; /* The curve radius */
  --w:55%;  /* The width of the left part (i.e distance of the curve from the left) */
  --c:red;  /* Color of the curve*/
}
.line:before,
.line:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  height:calc(50% - var(--l)); /* each one will take half the height minus border width*/
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:var(--c);
}
/* Left part */
.line:before {
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   width:var(--w);
   border-width:0 var(--l) var(--l) 0; /* Right & Bottom*/
   border-radius:0 0 var(--r) 0; /* Bottom-right*/
}
/* Right part*/
.line:after {
   top:0;
   right:calc(-1 * var(--l)); /* Move slightly to the right to have a perfect join */
   width:calc(100% - var(--w));
   border-width:var(--l) 0 0 var(--l); /* Top & Left */
   border-radius:var(--r) 0 0 0; /* Top-Left*/
}

/* curved line end*/

/*straight line comment out*/
/* .line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; put line behind the boxes
} */


#box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

#box3 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">A</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">B</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">C</div>

<div class="line" id="line" data-connect="#box1,#box2"></div>
<div class="line" id="line2" data-connect="#box1,#box3"></div>
   

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I am close but there is something which i am not getting right. Please help me to solve this one. Sometime boxes are also not able to drag but if i comment out **curved line css** and un- commnent  the **straight line css** which is also written in comment, boxes becomes smooth dragabble.

I would also appreciate if someone uses mathematic ways to solve this one like cubic bezier curve.

Comment: Must have the curve 150px height? If you set the curve height to 30px (.line {
  height:30px}) , then it works properly.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. But seems like i am loosing smoothness of the curve.

Comment: @LeventeGabos can u help me for making more perfect diagram. Lines should be at the edge of every box

Comment: Do you need the curve? with simple line would be definitely easier

Comment: i need curve. I already did with lines :)

Comment: the problem with your curve is that the leftside, rightside enpoints are not on the same vertical position. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: @LeventeGabos what shd i do to reach that goal?